# Parametric Equations Orientation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles, parametric, orientation

I am super confused on how to make a circle or ellipse go clockwise and anti clockwise in parametric equations. Therefore, I cannot finish these problems.

1. Write, in parametric form, the equations for an ellipse that in centered at $(0,0)$, starts at $(0,4)$, passes through $(3,0)$ and moves anti clockwise.
2. $(x+1)^2 + (y-3)^2 = 16$ is the equation of a circle in Cartesian form right the parametric equations that would have the same graph, start at $(-5,3)$, and go clockwise.
3. Write the parametric equation of a circle centered at $(-2, 4)$, has a radius of $3$, starts at $(-2, 7)$, and goes clockwise.

Again, please explain how to make the ending parametric equations be clockwise and anti clockwise. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

(cos t, sin t) goes counter clockwise.
(cos -t, sin -t) goes clockwise.